# What framework should be used to develop Android automation?

Tags: android, appium, selendroid

I try to use automation by launching Android app or browser.

When I use this automation, I need to be able to change the sensor value of my Android device or change the name of my device to change the browser's preferences.

Change the user-agent value of the browser, or change the tilt sensor value of the mobile phone.

I looked into the appium or seldroid, but I don't know if I can perform the above function. Is there another framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With android itself you can perform a lot of testing stuff like shown in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview).
To get a further understanding I suggest to read the following articles:

- [Sensor stack](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-stack?hl=en)
- [Android Sensor Integration](https://www.inovex.de/de/blog/android-sensor-integration-part-1-sensor-stack-and-kernel-module/)

Framework that can change sensor value and the device name are (I checked):

- [BrowserStack](https://stackshare.io/appium/alternatives)
- [Appium](https://appium.io/)

To get a detailed overview and more usefull frameworks compared, [Perfecto](https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/perfecto/automation-testing/automation_testing.htm) will help you to figure out what to use.

Good luck  with testing and automation! Cheers :)